# Cannot push git commit to github repo using Zend Studio 10.0.1

Tags: git, github, zend-studio

I am able to hit the commit button in zend studio for eclipse in but nothing seems to get pushed to the git hub. I downloaded Zend 10.6 trial and it seems to work fine. I think there is an issue with my version finding Git? I updated the software. In the new one, I just hit "commit and push" and it works seamlessly but in my version theres only a commit button and it never makes it to the github server?

Answer (score 0):

Git is distributed source control. Unlike something like SVN, you do not commit to a central repository. You commit only and always to your local repository. You can then push a series of commits to a peer repository, one of which is treated as the authoritative repository like on github, but you *must* push the changes.

If there is not *commit and push* button in your version of zend, you must find the push button (sometimes called synchronize branch/repo) or push from the command line. To push from the command line, open your favorite command processor or shell, change to the directory of your git repository and type: `git push origin master`. This assumes your remote is named `origin` which is the default and usually the case and your branch is named `master`, also the default and usually the case. Replace these as necessary for your setup.